# How to echo within echo (Twig)

Tags: php, twig, pyrocms

I have a problem using Twig in Pyrocms. I am trying to echo a variable within a shorthand if statement in Twig.

```
style="background-image: {{ (not link.bgcolor is empty ? 'linear-gradient(transparent, {{link.bgcolor}}),' : '')|raw }} url('{{link.image.url()}}');"
```

The statement is correct, but the displayed value actually is `linear-gradient(transparent, {{link.bgcolor}}),` the `{{link.bgcolor}}` is not getting parsed by Twig. How can I use `{{}}` tags within another `{{}}` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already in Twig-context, since you've opened it with `{{`. So you can refer to variables without adding an additional `{{ ... }}`. You just need to get out of the string context and concatenate the variable with the concatenation operator `~`. It should then look something like this:

```
{{ (not link.bgcolor is empty ? 'linear-gradient(transparent, ' ~ link.bgcolor ~ '),' : '')|raw }}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I tried concatenating, but with a dot as in PHP. Didn't know about the `~` operator.

Comment: Keep an eye out on the field type presenters being tested here. `{{ dd(link.bgcolor) }}` might be a presenter which will always be true even if no value. `link.bgcolor.value` might be safer to test if link is a stream entry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat that output,

```
{{ not link.bgcolor is empty ? 'linear-gradient(transparent, '~link.bgcolor~'),' : '' }}
```